# ORACLE paganiation with out sort field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-tuning

I have a view, which doesn't have any unique column to determine the sort. View is a union all of two large tables. 
I need paganiation support with out sort. I did some research on that, came to know paganiation will fall fail if we don't use order. It may come duplicate sets if we use rownum.

How to overcome that issue? Is there any work around on that without sort?

Comment: why do you need uniqueness to sort?